# Question with the sequence of events (Controller Index, Base OnActionExecuting) between Controller and ControllerBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm trying to understand the sequence of events in some legacy code when it comes to the HomeController and a ControllerBase.

What I have is this is the HomeController:

```
public override async Task<ActionResult> Index()
```

and this in the ControllerBase

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

Both methods have code impacting the same underlying business object, but I can't seem to work out the sequence of events as they seem to be "stepping on each other" when updating the object.

Simply put, does the OnActionExecuting run BEFORE the Index method in the HomeController or After  (or both)?